# Как вытянуть значения? Mapping

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

В общем есть 2 класса, а в них поля:

```
City
@property (nonatomic) int id;
@property (nonatomic) int country;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *title;

User
@property (nonatomic) NSString *last_name;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *first_name;
@property (nonatomic) City *city;
```

Заполняю данными:

```
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in [responseData objectForKey:@"response"][@"items"]) {
    user = [[User alloc] init];
    for (NSString *key in [dictionary allKeys]) {
        if ([user respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(key)]) {
            [user setValue:[dictionary objectForKey:key] forKey:key];
        }
    }
    [arrayFriends addObject:user];
}
```

Вытягиваю в список:

```
user = [arrayFriends objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

[[friendsCell labelFirstName] setText:[user first_name]];
```

А вот когда вытягиваю значение из user.city то твориться непонятное, там нулл - пустые значения

```
[[friendsCell labelLastName] setText:[user.city title]];
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно вытянуть значения?

Comment: null всегда останется null, если он в JSON так приходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
[[friendsCell labelFirstName] setText:[[user city] valueForKey:@"title"]];
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.